# Customizing ArcGIS Online application template and uploading it back to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online

Is it possible to customize a template for web application in ArcGIS Online?

What I mean, none of the templates 100% suits our needs so I'm wondering if I could download the code of basic viewer, let's say, add required functions and upload it back to ArcGIS Online and use it for our maps?

Comment: I think uploading back to ArcGIS Online not possible but you can integrate it your site..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question Yes its possible to customize the templates and I have customized one template & go though following links which will be helpful/guide for you..

Useful links for you :

[Create Customized Mapping Applications Using Esri's Web Map and Application Templates in ArcGIS Online](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0712/create-customized-mapping-applications-using-esris-web-map-and-application-templates-in-arcgis-online.html)

[Free Video (Getting Started with Map Templates)](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&CourseID=1723)

[Lots of Web Application Templates](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=esri_en&title=Web%20Application%20Templates)

[Creating web application templates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#/Creating_web_application_templates/010q00000072000000/)

I hope it will help you..thanks

Comment: Hi,                                                          Thx for asnwers. Exactly this I want, to upload my modified template to ArcGIS online. I have successfully modified BasicViewer and now I want to use it from template gallery, in ArcGIS online for organisation.

Comment: To be clear though, you aren't actually uploading your template to ArcGIS Online. You host the template on your server and create a link to it in AGOL. When someone uses it in AGOL, they are sending a appid / webmapid to your server (and optionally configuration parameters, if you've set them up.)

Comment: @awesomo that's true : )

Comment: Thanks all for answers.  This is is exactly scenario I am trying to avoid, not using my server anymore

Comment: I have seen a number of users that download templates, tweak them with additional styling or configuration parameters, and then upload them to AWS-S3 (very cheap) and register the templates back in ArcGIS Online so they can be used to create additional web apps from the existing template.  Only one template is stored in S3, but it is used for the other apps that are created from it.  Its worth exploring as you can tinker the templates to be more closely aligned to your organisations branding.

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](http://developernetwork.conterra.de/en/content/building-hosted-app-templates-arcgis-online) to customising an app and then using it as a template has some useful tips, although links to the sample data don't work. Unfortunately though, once you have customised an app in even the most minor way, it can't be hosted by ArcGIS Online - you will need to host it yourself.